# KnockoutJS - ViewModel Abstracion

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js, viewmodel, abstraction

***UPDATE*** (see below)

I understand the basics of KnockoutJS. When creating a table viewmodel, one would use `<tr data-bind="foreach: rows">`

Now I'm trying to abstract the table viewmodel, so that I can create multiple tables with the same behaviour (sorting, editing, pagination, etc..). So what I'm aiming for is something like this:

*HTML*

```
<div class="table a" data-bind="myTableBinding: aTableViewModel"></div>
<div class="table b" data-bind="myTableBinding: anotherTableViewmodel"></div>
```

*Main ViewModel*

```
var MainViewModel = function () {
  this.aTableViewModel = new AbstractTableViewModel({
      columns: [...]
      initialSort: [...]
  });
  this.anotherTableViewModel = new AbstractTableViewModel({
      columns: [...]
      initialSort: [...]
  });
};
```

My first try was mimicking the example [simpleGrid] plugin (@ http://knockoutjs.com/examples/resources/knockout.simpleGrid.1.3.js) that the KnockoutJS docs use for the [Paged grid] example.

I'm not really sure, but I think that the basic concept of abstraction isn't represented well in this plugin. When I tried to include css class into the `<th>` elements like so: `<th class="col col-id">`, `<th class="col col-name">`, etc, I found out this wasn't easy (impossible?) using `data-bind` attributes.

The `data-bind` attributes probably shouldn't be used for this stuff through, because these classes won't change -- they are part of a higher abstraction level: we should actually insert these classes with jQuery.tmpl or Underscore's templating system. But then I got an error saying that [This template system doesn't support use of the `foreach` binding] (or something like that).

My second try therefore was to implement the abstraction as it should be implemented: with the table properties (columns, etc) at another "abstraction level" than the table data:

1. Create the basic `<tr data-bind="foreach: rows">` html at instantiation of a new specific table view model, using an "abstract" template -- this I simply did with Underscore's _.template.
2. Let this specific viewmodel use the above html as usual.

In CoffeeScript:

```
do ->
  ko.dataTable =
    ViewModel: (config) ->
      @id = config.id
      @columns = config.columns
      @pageSize = config.pageSize ? 9999
      @sortColumn = ko.observable (config.sortColumn ? @columns[0].col)
      @sortOrder = ko.observable (config.sortOrder ? "asc")
      @data = ko.observableArray (config.data ? [])
      null

  ko.bindingHandlers.dataTable =
    init: (el, acc) ->
      viewModel = acc()
      $(el).find("div:first").html dataTableTemplateMaker viewModel
      # ??? [A] ko.applyBindings viewModel, $(el).find("table")[0]
      # ??? [B] controlsDescendantBindings: yes
      null
    update: (el, acc) ->
      viewModel = acc()
      # ??? [C]
      null
```

And then:

```
<div data-bind="dataTable: groupTable">
```

and:

```
class ViewModel
  constructor: ->
    @groupTable = new ko.dataTable.ViewModel
      id: "grouptable"
      columns: [
        { col: "num",     title: "Groep", editable: yes }
        { col: "subject", title: "Vak" }
        { col: "year",    title: "Jaar" }
        { col: "level",   title: "Niveau" }
        { col: "day",     title: "Dag" }
        { col: "hour",    title: "Uur" }
        { col: "place",   title: "Lokaal", editable: yes }
      ]
      pageSize: 10
      sortColumn: "num"
      sortOrder: "asc"
      data: [] # [D]
```

... in which `???` marks the spot(s) where my confusion lies.

Say I do not insert lines `[A]` and `[B]`. Then of course KnockoutJS tells me that the bindings are all messed up within the html for my specific viewmodel (which is inserted into the `<div>`. If I do insert lines `[A]` and `[B]`, then it does work for initial data (at `[D]`), but after that does not respond.

Alltogether: I'm quite confused about something simple as abstracting a viewmodel. Isn't there a standard solution to this in KnockoutJS? (I've googled but couldn't quite find anything...) Or am I just messing it up myself (quite possible)? ;)

***UPDATE***

I solved the problem (but maybe it's not the best / well at all -- what is your opinion?), for completeness' sake: (a condensed version -- of course you'd probably also want to observe the rows  individually etc..)

*HTML* (yes, that is purposefully a string passed to the binding handler)

```
<div data-bind="myTableBinding: 'viewModelPropertyHoldingTableViewModel'"></div>
```

*CoffeeScript*

```
class MainViewModel
  constructor: ->
    @viewModelPropertyHoldingTableViewModel = new TableViewModel <options>
    null

class TableViewModel
  constructor: (options) ->
    @columns = options.columns
    @rows = ko.observableArray (options.rows ? [])
    [...]
    null

tableTemplateMaker = _.template '
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        [% _.map(tableViewModel.columns, function (column) { %]
        <th>[%= column.title %]</th>
        [% } %]
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: rows">
      <tr>
        [% _.map(tableViewModel.columns, function (column) { %]
        <td data-bind="text: [%= column.id %]"></td>
        [% } %]
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
'

ko.bindingHandlers.myTableBinding =
  init: (element, viewModelPropertyNameAccessor, _, mainViewModel) ->
    tableViewModelProperty = viewModelPropertyNameAccessor()
    tableViewModel = mainViewModel[tableViewModelProperty]
    $(element).html tableTemplateMaker
      tableViewModelProperty: tableViewModelProperty
      tableViewModel: tableViewModel
    null

m = new MainViewModel
ko.applyBindings m

m.viewModelPropertyHoldingTableViewModel.data.push [...]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "after that does not respond"? Are you doing `var vm = new ViewModel()` and `vm.groupTable.data(newData);` ?

Comment: Actually (!) I was doing `vm.groupTable.data().push`... But now I understand how stupid that was ;)

Comment: Yeah, but you can actually do `vm.groupTable.data.push`. Without `()` should work as expected. :)

Comment: What exactly was your issue with the simplegrid implementation? You mention abstraction but your implementation seems exactly as "absrtact" as the simple grid. Not sure why you pass the viewmodel as a string, you really don't need to. Also, I would recommend next time not showing code in CS, just because it reduces the burden on the community to have to know an intermediate language in order to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel? :P

https://github.com/CogShift/Knockout.Extensions